# openni2_launch doesn't work with carmine 1.09 connected to USB3.0

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I have a trouble that **openni2_launch doesn't work.**
I'm using **carmine 1.09 connected to USB3.0**, because my MacBookPro doesn't have any USB2.0 ports.

**I've already carried out [firmware update](http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/wiki/index.php/4._Updating_Firmware_for_Primesense) for carmine 1.09**, however it still doesn't work and I have the following errors.
Actually, the errors are the same as the errors which I had before I update carmine's firmware.

```
[ INFO] [1415845653.463960586]: Device "1d27/0609@1/12" with serial number "" connected

[ INFO] [1415845653.468566285]: No matching device found.... waiting for devices. Reason: openni2_wrapper::OpenNI2Device::OpenNI2Device(const string&) @ /tmp/buildd/ros-indigo-openni2-camera-0.2.2-0trusty-20141015-0837/src/openni2_device.cpp @ 74 : Initialize failed

    Could not open "1d27/0609@1/12": Failed to open the USB device!
```

**How can I solve this problem ?**

---

- OS : Ubuntu 14.04
- ROS : Indigo
- Hardware : MacBookPro (which has 2 USB3.0 ports)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197318/openni2_launch-doesn%27t-work-with-carmine-1.09-connected-to-usb3.0/) by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 721 on 2014-11-12

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like you now have a device ID of 1d27:0609. Unfortunately, the 0609 is not in the default udev rules that get installed with the libopenni2 debian in ROS. Check your /lib/udev/rules.d/40-libopenni2-0.rules file and see if it contains a line with product ID 0609. It probably won't, so add the following to a file in /etc/udev/rules.d (such as /etc/udev/rules.d/40-libopenni2-0.rules):

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idProduct}=="0609", ATTR{idVendor}=="1d27", MODE:="0666", OWNER:="root", GROUP:="video"
```

(don't modify the /lib/udev version, as it will get overwritten the next time you update debs)

Unfortunately, even with updated firmware and proper udev rules, these devices can be unreliable on USB3. One thing that I have found to work (sometimes) is to blacklist the "usb_snd_audio" kernel module, as this is used for the microphones on the sensor, and it appears the sensor audio hardware is quite unreliable. The other thing to check is that you actually have a valid udev rule.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) on 2014-11-17**:
Thank you !! I could solved the problem thanks to you !!
Now carmine 1.09 works well with Ubuntu 14.04, ROS Indigo and the latest MacBookPro's USB 3.0.
Strangely, when I connect it to USB port on right side, it doesn't work. However it doesn't matter.
Thank you !

**Comment by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on 2014-11-25**:
This does not work on Ubuntu 12.04, ROS Hydro ... (Carmine has the Firmware update)

**Comment by [ryohei](https://answers.ros.org/users/20938/ryohei/) on 2014-11-26**:
I have the same problem on ubuntu 12.04, hydro.

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2014-11-26**:
12.04 version of libopenni2 is too old for the upgraded firmware.

**Comment by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on 2014-11-26**:
I see. Is it possible to use drivers compiled from source?

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2014-11-27**:
You could build a new libopenni2 deb using git-buildpackage and install it, and then build openni2_camera from source. The repository for libopenni2 as packaged for ROS indigo is here: http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-multimedia/openni2.git/

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2015-07-13**:
Thanks, fergs. Did this a while ago and forgot this important step.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I compiled openni2 and openni2_camera from source and it works

https://github.com/jsk-ros-pkg/jsk_recognition/blob/master/install_latest_openni2.sh

---

Originally posted by [Ryohei Ueda](https://answers.ros.org/users/59/ryohei-ueda/) with karma: 317 on 2014-11-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1